# Jenkins gives error on configuring Amazon EC2 cloud

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins server with EC2 plugin such that all builds are executed by the EC2 instances, which act as agents for the master server.

While trying to save the cloud configuration for 'Amazon EC2' cloud in the Jenkins master, it fails with an exception. Checking in the Jenkins logs, I see this exception:

```
Caught unhandled exception with ID f6d45d51-fb00-4d1c-a474-0a55dd5ee710
org.kohsuke.stapler.WrongTypeException: Got type array but no lister class found for type class java.lang.String
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:724)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:787)
    Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the instanceCapStr parameter of 
the constructor public hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud
(java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:789)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:83)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:678)
    Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud from 
{
    "cloudName":"ec2-cloud",
    "includeUser":["false","false"],
    "credentialsId":"",
    "useInstanceProfileForCredentials":true,
    "altEC2Endpoint":"",
    "region":"eu-west-1",
    "sshKeysCredentialsId":"jenkins-slave-ssh-key",
    "instanceCapStr":["",""],
    "noDelayProvisioning":false,
    "roleArn":"",
    "roleSessionName":"",
    "templates":{
        "description":"Amazon Linux 2 AMI",
        "ami":"ami-0bb3fad3c0286ebd5",
        "type":"T2Micro",
        "ebsOptimized":true,
        "monitoring":true,
        "t2Unlimited":false,
        "zone":"",
        "securityGroups":"",
        "remoteFS":"/var/lib/jenkins",
        "remoteAdmin":"ec2-user",
        "":"0",
        "amiType":{
            "rootCommandPrefix":"",
            "slaveCommandPrefix":"",
            "slaveCommandSuffix":"",
            "sshPort":"22",
            "stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData",
            "$class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData"
        },
        "labelString":"ec2",
        "mode":"EXCLUSIVE",
        "idleTerminationMinutes":"30",
        "initScript":"",
        "tmpDir":"",
        "userData":"",
        "numExecutors":"",
        "jvmopts":"",
        "stopOnTerminate":false,
        "subnetId":"",
        "useDedicatedTenancy":false,
        "name":"","value":""
        },
    "minimumNumberOfInstances":"0",
    "minimumNumberOfSpareInstances":"0",
    "iamInstanceProfile":"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance-profile/jenkins_server_role",
    "deleteRootOnTermination":true,
    "useEphemeralDevices":true,
    "customDeviceMapping":"",
    "launchTimeoutStr":"",
    "associatePublicIp":false,
    "connectionStrategy":"PRIVATE_IP",
    "connectBySSHProcess":false,
    "hostKeyVerificationStrategy":"CHECK_NEW_HARD",
    "maxTotalUses":"-1",
    "nodeProperties":{"stapler-class-bag":"true"}
},"stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud","$class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud"}
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:681)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:474)
        at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:598)
```

I do see the property 'Instance cap' in two different locations in the Jenkins UI. My understanding is that one is for configuring a  max limit on the *total number of instances allowed in the entire cloud*,
and the other property describes a max limit on the *number of instances for the particular AMI*.

Is this a Jenkins issue? Or is it something wrong with the configuration I've provided?

NOTE: I'm okay with providing the configuration as code rather than via the Jenkins UI. If anyone is able to provide the same configuration through code, that is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually ended up configuring this using a groovy script run in the **Script Console** in the Jenkins UI. The groovy script I used is:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.ec2.*
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType
  
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def ec2_cloud_name = 'ec2-cloud'
def ec2_instance_cap = 5

def worker_description = 'jenkins-slave running in ec2 instance'
def worker_label_string = 'ec2-slave'

def ami_id = 'ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
def security_groups = 'sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
def subnet_id = 'subnet-xxxxxxxx'
def instance_type = 't2.micro'
def instance_profile_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance-profile/jenkins_server_role'

def number_of_executors = 2

def ec2_tags = [
  new EC2Tag('Name', 'jenkins-slave-instance')
]

def priv_key_txt = '''
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<My Private key>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
'''

def worker_ami = new SlaveTemplate(
   // String ami
  ami_id,
  // String zone
  '',
  // SpotConfiguration spotConfig
  null,
  // String securityGroups
  security_groups,
  // String remoteFS
  '',
  // InstanceType type
  InstanceType.fromValue(instance_type),
  // boolean ebsOptimized
  false,
  // String labelString
  worker_label_string,
  // Node.Mode mode
  Node.Mode.NORMAL,
  // String description
  worker_description,
  // String initScript
  '',
  // String tmpDir
  '',
  // String userData
  '',
  // String numExecutors
  "${number_of_executors}",
  // String remoteAdmin
  '',
  // AMITypeData amiType
  new UnixData(null, null, null, null),
  // String jvmopts
  '',
  // boolean stopOnTerminate
  false,
  // String subnetId
  subnet_id,
  // List<EC2Tag> tags
  ec2_tags,
  // String idleTerminationMinutes
  '30',
  // int minimumNumberOfInstances
  0,
  // int minimumNumberOfSpareInstances
  0,
  // string instanceCapStr
  '3',
  // string iamInstanceProfile
  'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance-profile/jenkins_server_role',
  // boolean deleteRootOnTermination
  true,
  // boolean useEphemeralDevices
  true,
  // boolean useDedicatedTenancy
  false,
  // String launchTimeoutStr
  '1800',
  // boolean associatePublicIp
  false,
  // String customDeviceMapping
  '',
  // boolean connectBySSHProcess
  false,
  // boolean monitoring
  false,
  // boolean t2Unlimited
  false,
  // Enum connectionStrategy
  ConnectionStrategy.PRIVATE_IP,
  // int maxTotalUses
  3,
  // List<? extends NodeProperty<?>> nodeProperties
  [],
  // HostKeyVerificationStrategyEnum 
  HostKeyVerificationStrategyEnum.CHECK_NEW_HARD
)

def new_cloud = new AmazonEC2Cloud(
   // String cloudName
  ec2_cloud_name,
  // boolean useInstanceProfileForCredentials
  true,
  // String credentialsId
  '',
  // String region
  'eu-west-1',
  // String privateKey
  priv_key_txt,
  // String sshKeysCredentialsId
  'jenkins-slave-ssh-key',
  // String instanceCapStr
  "3",
  // List<? extends SlaveTemplate> templates
  [worker_ami],
  // String roleArn
  null,
  // String roleSessionName
  null
)

instance.clouds.add(new_cloud)
```

Strange thing is, after creating the config by running this script, **now** I am able to edit and save the created config via the Jenkins UI.

Comment: Thank you, I was running into the same issue and this unblocked me.